# how to add certificate in cacerts folder in android emulator 3.1

Tags: android, security, penetration-testing, application-security

I am trying to intercept HTTPS traffic for native app in android emulator 3.1. However there is no cacerts.bks file present in the file system. All certs are stored under /system/etc/security/cacerts/. Any help in adding the cert and intercepting the request using proxy will be appreciated.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have not mentioned the proxy tool that you are using, I am going to assume it is Burp.

As a first step, export the certificate of Burp. To do this use the guide on below link and after "View Certificate step export the certificate onto your system. Verify that the file is saved with the extension ".crt"

http://portswigger.net/burp/help/proxy_options_installingCAcert.html

Now, copy this file into the sdcard of the emulator. You can use adb push to achieve this.

In the emulator navigate to Settings -> Security -> Credential storage: Install certificates from SD card

It will prompt you to enter a PIN code, enter the secret code and the certificate will be added. Now, access any HTTPS site you should be able to intercept in your proxy.